# Upper East Side to I-95 South via Car

Tags: driving, new-york-city, routes, new-jersey

If leaving Saturday 7AM from  78th and 2nd, two routes are considered for arriving at I-95 south:

1. Lincoln-Tunnel via 2nd Avenue
2. 278 to 95 via nearby FDR through Brooklyn / Staten Island

Which is the preferred route and why?

Comment: [Google also likes the idea](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/2nd+Ave+%26+E+78th+St,+New+York,+NY+10075/40.176631,-74.6308453/@40.7441228,-74.0827358,11.61z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c258bf111fdb2d:0xb0bb61e4e13dd458!2m2!1d-73.9555581!2d40.7726606!1m0!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1540018800!3e0) of going north and taking the George Washington Bridge. A few miles longer, but likely about the same time. Since all the routes are roughly the same, I'd personally fire up Waze when I wanted to leave and go with whatever is best at the moment (you never know if there'll be an accident or construction).

Comment: Have you worked out the tolls in both cases?  I believe the Lincoln Tunnel is free westbound, though I suppose you'll travel further on the NJ Turnpike and pay a little more in tolls that way.  But on route #2, you have substantial tolls on the VZ bridge and possibly also the Brooklyn-Battery Tunnel if you take it.

Comment: @NateEldredge   Your statement above is correct.

Comment: Not sure if this question should be here. It's not really got anything to do with travel. Google Maps/Apple Maps/Waze and countless other apps would better answer this question. This doesn't ask about any points of interest along the route, nor covers any significant distance. I'm not sure if we want to provide generally driving directions here on this forum. The other thing with driving and choosing routes is that it's very contextual, the weather, accidents, road closures etc can't really be predicted in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of personal preference, either one of these two or a third which google maps found for Zach Lipton, going north to start with and using the Washington Bridge, which while a little longer is likely as fast.

All things being even (in terms of time / traffic), a good way to decide is how much toll you need to pay, your choice #2 seems to be more expensive.

You can find the best route on the day by checking how busy the roads are, Waze is one way, but listening to traffic information on the radio works still in most cases.

In the end it will likely fall to what roads you like best or dislike least, and whether you feel the higher toll is worth it.